# strtotime return false while converting date string

Tags: php, datetime, laravel, strtotime

Using php 5.4.34 And **Laravel 4** with apache 2.2.22 and Ubuntu.

I try to convert the string `'2050-10-13'` to a date and it always return false.

```
var_dump(strtotime('2050-10-13')); ==> false
var_dump(strtotime('13-10-2050')); ==> false
var_dump(strtotime('2050/10/13')); ==> false
var_dump(strtotime('13/10/2050')); ==> false
```

I tried to add before :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Brussels');
```

OR

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
```

I doesn't change anything.

in `app/config/app.php` I have :

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
'locale' => 'en',
```

What could be the problem ??

Comment: cf [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), in particular, the second note 32bit vs 64bit systems and the valid time ranges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2050` cannot be represented internally on 32 bit systems.
Timestamp have a limit to 2038 because the max value for a 32-bit integer is `2,147,483,647`, that is: `2038-01-19T03:14:08+0000Z`

You have just experienced the `year2038` bug.

### How to fix

Don't use timestamp. Instead use a more robust library such as `new \DateTime('2050-10-13');` and of course on your Database use `Date` field.

Comment: 2050 _can_ be represented internally, provided you're on a 64bit system

Comment: @dynamic: a `long` of 4 bytes, you mean... PHP integers are represented internally by the C type `long` :-P (pedantic, I know)

Comment: That's right, but Integer (in english speaking) include long :)

Comment: `var_dump(strtotime('13-10-1999'));` =>  `int 939762000`

Comment: @BastienSander: check the default format for the timezone you're using: is it `m-d-Y` or `d-m-Y`, in the first case: 13 is not a valid month

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using a function that cannot cope with dates so far in the future on a 32 bit system.

Use DateTime instead it will cope quite happily with such dates:-

```
$date = new \DateTime('2050-10-13');
var_dump($date);
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/da5GB)

Comment: And this answers the _"What could be the problem"_ question how, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Adding answer into dynamic answer. Timestamp have a limit to 2038 because The maximum value of a 32-bit integer is 2,147,483,647. If you add +1 to that, you get -2,147,483,647. 2,147,483,647 seconds from 01-01-1970 00:00:00 is January 19, 2038. If you add one more second, you get a date somewhere in 1902.

Hard luck this time.

Comment: Again, pedantic, but technically: signed integer overflow results in undefined behavior, so in theory, anything could happen. 99% of the time, `INT_MAX + 1 == INT_MIN`. In theory however, a segfault or an LPT0 printer on fire error is just as likely